# Rails 5 - how to remove twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and install it manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In project I'm using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, but for some reasons (e.g. it blocks another gem version) I want to uninstall it and add manually (not by gem) into my project. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall a gem just run:

```
gem uninstall <gem-name>
```

From looking at the docs here [DOCS](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), I don't believe there is a way to install it manually without running `bundle install`

Comment: I just uninstall gem like u said and download bootstrap files from website. Thanks for help :)